# Count occurrences of each word in a given text file stored based on date

Tags: python, date, text, count

I currently have a **text file** consisting of rows with the timestamp and name when a person sent a message. Please see below: [Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZKzq.jpg)

```
8/29/19, 2:03 PM - Michael: ...
8/29/19, 3:05 PM - Frank: ...
8/29/19, 4:01 PM - Tom: ...
8/29/19, 5:26 PM - Amy: ...
8/29/19, 6:46 PM - Tom: ...
8/29/19, 7:24 PM - Frank: ...
8/29/19, 9:55 PM - Amy: ...
8/30/19, 11:35 AM - Frank: ...
8/30/19, 12:39 PM - Johnny: ...
9/3/19, 1:18 AM - Frank: ...
9/3/19, 2:23 AM - Frank: ...
9/3/19, 3:16 PM - Frank: ...
9/3/19, 4:53 PM - Johnny: ...
9/4/19, 9:01 AM - Frank: ...
9/4/19, 11:45 AM - Frank: ...
9/4/19, 1:04 PM - Johnny: ...
9/4/19, 1:42 PM - Johnny: ...
9/4/19, 2:03 PM - Amy: ...
9/4/19, 4:12 PM - Johnny: ...
9/4/19, 6:27 PM - Amy: ...
9/4/19, 9:08 PM - Johnny: ...
.   .      .
.   .      .
.   .      .
```

I would like to count the occurrence when a person sent a message based on the date in python. I would like to output the following:[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIwvX.png)

```
                 Michael  Frank   Tom    Amy     Johnny

      8/29/2019     1        2      2     2       0
      8/30/2019     0        1      0     0       1
      8/31/2019     0        0      0     0       0
      9/1/2019      0        0      0     0       0
      9/2/2019      0        0      0     0       0
      9/3/2019      0        3      0     0       1
      9/4/2019      0        2      0     2       4
      9/5/2019                  
      9/6/2019                  
      9/7/2019                  
      9/8/2019
```

A first-time poster so please forgive me if I don't have the formatting correct. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm pretty new on SO myself, so I don't know what's normal here. But, I think you @Michael should probably present some start at the Python program you need. Before I can suggest a program structure to you you would need to answer: 1) how do you want to establish the starting date to be used (possibly doing this on the fly based on the first line of input)  2) how do you want to establish the set of names (also done using the first date, or done using all the dates, ie by reading the the whole input?)  3) do you want to be able to handle enormous inputs or just modest ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas to help:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txtfile=StringIO("""8/29/19, 2:03 PM - Michael: ...
8/29/19, 3:05 PM - Frank: ...
8/29/19, 4:01 PM - Tom: ...
8/29/19, 5:26 PM - Amy: ...
8/29/19, 6:46 PM - Tom: ...
8/29/19, 7:24 PM - Frank: ...
8/29/19, 9:55 PM - Amy: ...
8/30/19, 11:35 AM - Frank: ...
8/30/19, 12:39 PM - Johnny: ...
9/3/19, 1:18 AM - Frank: ...
9/3/19, 2:23 AM - Frank: ...
9/3/19, 3:16 PM - Frank: ...
9/3/19, 4:53 PM - Johnny: ...
9/4/19, 9:01 AM - Frank: ...
9/4/19, 11:45 AM - Frank: ...
9/4/19, 1:04 PM - Johnny: ...
9/4/19, 1:42 PM - Johnny: ...
9/4/19, 2:03 PM - Amy: ...
9/4/19, 4:12 PM - Johnny: ...
9/4/19, 6:27 PM - Amy: ...
9/4/19, 9:08 PM - Johnny: ...""")

df = pd.read_csv(txtfile, sep=',|-|:', header=None, index_col=[0], engine='python')
df_out = df[3].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
          Amy   Frank   Johnny   Michael   Tom
0                                             
8/29/19     2       2        0         1     2
8/30/19     0       1        1         0     0
9/3/19      0       3        1         0     0
9/4/19      2       2        4         0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this by iterating only once through the file would be with the help of defaultdict:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

occurrences = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        date = line.split(', ')[0]
        name = line.split(' - ')[1].split(': ')[0]
        occurrences[date][name] += 1
```

Occurrences would have the following data:

```
8/29/19: {'Michael': 1, 'Frank': 2, 'Tom': 2, 'Amy': 2}
8/30/19: {'Frank': 1, 'Johnny': 1}
9/3/19: {'Frank': 3, 'Johnny': 1}
9/4/19: {'Frank': 2, 'Johnny': 4, 'Amy': 2}
```

**Edit:** This would print out the exact output OP wanted:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

occurrences = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    start_date = lines[0].split(' - ')[0]
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')
    end_date = lines[-1].split(' - ')[0]
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')

    dates = []

    for n in (range(int((end_date - start_date).days))):
        single_date = start_date + timedelta(n)
        dates.append(single_date.date())

    authors = set()

    for line in lines:
        name = line.split(' - ')[1].split(': ')[0]
        authors.add(name)
        date = line.split(' - ')[0]
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p').date()
        occurrences[date][name] += 1

    print('\t\t', end='')
    for name in authors:
        print (name, end='\t')
    print()

    for date in dates:
        print(date.strftime('%m/%d/%y'), end='\t')
        for name in authors:
            print(occurrences[date][name], end='\t')
        print()
```

There is room for improvement on this solution since it completely disregards performance.

Comment: This answer does not sort the output by date. It only assumes that defaultdict will return in sorted key order (I don't think that's a guarantee). More importantly maybe, sorting dates as strings does not give you sorted dates. For example, how will these dates sort: 8/29/19, 1/29/19, 11/29/19, 2/29/18?   Secondly, this answer should provide output in the format indicated - that is, a table with columns and zeros for cells with having no count for that date.

Comment: Oh, and this answer does not fill in dates to be all zeroes, as found in the example output.  @Coka - I'm not trying to be critical. Just pointing thins out in this 'fun little exercise'

Comment: @BillHuneke exactly. I would like the output to be in a table with 0 if a person does not send a message for that date

Comment: In that case, the solution becomes more complicated. You would need to build a list of the dates between the starting and ending date, as well as a list of all the authors. Then populating the table would be easier.

Comment: I edited my original answer with a solution that prints out the exact output as @Michael requested.